# Python subprocess - write multiple stdin

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I need to open an R script and supply it with input formulated by a separate python script. The `subprocess` module seems to be a good way to do this.

I have encountered some puzzling results though, namely that I can apparently write once and only once via `p.stdin`.  Here is what I have so far:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['r --no-save'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
p.stdin.write("source('myrscript.R')\n")
p.stdin.write('myfirstinput')
```

What happens when I run this code is that the first instance of `stdin.write()` performs as expected (and opens my R script), but the second line does nothing, and the subprocess (really, the R script) exits with an error, indicating that the subprocessed received no input where input was expected and therefore terminated.

N.B. -  In a perfect world, I would just interact directly through R, but this particular script requires complex inputs that cannot be entered directly for practical purposes. Also, rpy / rpy2 is not an option, because end-users of this script will not necessarily have access to that module or its dependencies. `rscript` is also not an option (for many reasons, but mainly because of variability in the end-users R configurations).

Finally, `p.communicate` is not an option, because apparently that will close the process after writing and I need to keep it open.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `flush()`ing `stdin` doesn't change anything?

Comment: good question, and no, including `p.stdin.flush()` between the write commands does does not change the result.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to open "r" and not "R"?

Comment: According to the subprocess module documentation for Popen...

Note

Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. As the pipes are not being read in the current process, the child process may block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer.

Maybe something wacky is going on in the script?  Have you tried just issuing 2 simple commands like, p.stdin.write("a = 7")  p.stdin.write("print(a)") instead of the script?

Comment: That was a helpful suggestion, thanks. It does indeed appear to be something internal to my script, because when I issue 2 separate commands, as you suggest, I get the expected behavior from `p.stdin.write()`.  I will troubleshoot the R script - many thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us how you access stdin in the R script? "/dev/stdin" or "stdin"? With the former one I experienced problems

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that question.  I can tell you though, that my R script does not explicitly call on either `/dev/stdin` or `stdin`

Comment: Uhm, ok. Do you have access to this script? At least the relevant parts where the standard input is read? To see why I asked check the notes at the end of help(stdin)

Comment: if the child R script reads directly from a terminal, you could try `pexpect`, `pty` modules to send/receive such input/output. Related: [Capture “Segmentation fault” message for a crashed subprocess: no out and err after a call to communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22250893/4279)

Answer (score 6):

What you need is to call `.communicate()`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(
    ['r', '--nosave'],
    stdin=PIPE,
    stdout=PIPE,
    stderr=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("source('myrscript.R')\n")
p.stdin.write('myfirstinput\n')
p.stdin.write('q\n')

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

print '---STDOUT---'
print stdout
print '---STDERR---'
print stderr
print '---'
```

#### Discussion

- I don't use the `shell=True` and it seems working with my *fake R* script since I don't have R install in my system. You might or might not need it.
- I prefer breaking the command line up into a list of string as shown, but a single string such as `r --nosave` will work as well; just don't do them both at the same time.
- Don't forget that `stdin.write()` does not write the new line character `\n`, you have to supply that yourself.

## Update

My first attempt was off the mark, I hope this second attempt gets closer. As  J.F. Sebastian suggested, you might want to use `pexpect`:

```
import pexpect
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prompt = '> ' # Don't know what the R prompt looks like
    lines = ['one', 'two', 'three']

    r = pexpect.spawn('r --no-save', logfile=sys.stdout)
    for line in lines:
        r.expect(prompt)
        r.sendline(line)

    # If you want to interact with your script, use these two lines
    # Otherwise, comment them out
    r.logfile = None # Turn off logging to sys.stdout
    r.interact()
```

#### Discussion

- You might need to install `pexpect`. I did it with `pip install pexpect`
- If you don't want to interact with the system, comment out the last two line, but make sure to send some signal for the R script to exit.
- `spawn()` returns a `spawn` object, see doc [here](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn).

Comment: OP already said that `p.communicate()` is not suitable because it waits for the process to complete. Also use `p.communicate("\n".join(["source('myrscript.R')", "myfirstinput", "q"]))` instead of `p.stdin.write()` calls otherwise you may cause a deadlock