# Capture "Segmentation fault" message for a crashed subprocess: no out and err after a call to communicate()

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, subprocess, fuzzing

I have problems using the subprocess module to obtain the output of crashed programs.
I'm using python2.7 and subprocess to call a program with strange arguments in order to get some segfaults
In order to call the program, I use the following code:

```
proc = (subprocess.Popen(called,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE))
out,err=proc.communicate()
print out,err
```

called is a list containing the name of the program and the argument (a string containing random bytes except the NULL byte which subprocess doesn't like at all)

The code behave and show me the stdout and stderr when the program doesn't crash, but when it does crash, out and err are empty instead of showing the famous "Segmentation fault".

I wish to find a way to obtain out and err even when the program crash.

I also tried the check_output / call / check_call methods

Some additional information:

- I'm running this script on an Archlinux 64 bits in a python virtual environment (shouldn't be something important here, but you never know :p)
- The segfault happens in the C program I'm trying to run and is a consequence of a buffer overflow
- The problem is that when the segfault occurs, I can't get the output of what happened with subprocess
- I get the returncode right: -11 (SIGSEGV)
- Using python i get:

  ```
    ./dumb2 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
    ('Exit code was:', -11) 
    ('Output was:', '') 
    ('Errors were:', '')
  ```
- While outside python I get:

  ```
   ./dumb2 $(perl -e "print 'A'x50")  
   BEGINNING OF PROGRAM 
   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   END OF THE PROGRAM
   Segmentation fault (core dumped)
  ```
- The return value of the shell is the same: echo $? returns 139 so -11 ($? & 128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came back here: it works like a charm with subprocess from python3 and if you are on linux, there is a backport to python2 called `subprocess32` which does work quite well

Older solution: I used pexpect and it works

```
def cmd_line_call(name, args):
    child = pexpect.spawn(name, args)
    # Wait for the end of the output
    child.expect(pexpect.EOF) 
    out = child.before # we get all the data before the EOF (stderr and stdout)
    child.close() # that will set the return code for us
    # signalstatus and existstatus read as the same (for my purpose only)
    if child.exitstatus is None:
        returncode = child.signalstatus
    else:
        returncode = child.exitstatus
    return (out, returncode)
```

PS: a little slower (because it spawns a pseudo tty)

Comment: try [`out, returncode = run(command, withexitstatus=1); signal = 128 - returncode`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253472/4279)

Comment: note: `child.before` is a string. It is not callable; remove `()`.

Comment: do not return signalstatus and exitstatus as the same value; they are not.

Comment: thx for the corrections J.F Sebastian :)
Your answer is much more complete, made it the right answer.

Comment: How do you distinguish `exitstatus == 11` and `signalstatus == 11`?

Comment: (in my case, any status that is not 0 was an error)

Comment: if you are only interested in whether it is zero or not then you could use `child.status`.

Answer (score 12):

`"Segmentation fault"` message might be generated by a shell. To find out, whether the process is kill by `SIGSEGV`, check `proc.returncode == -signal.SIGSEGV`.

If you want to see the message, you could run the command in the shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print out, err, proc.returncode
```

I've tested it with `shell_command="python -c 'from ctypes import *; memset(0,1,1)'"` that causes segfault and the message is captured in `err`.

If the message is printed directly to the terminal then you could use `pexpect` module to capture it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pipes import quote
from pexpect import run # $ pip install pexpect

out, returncode = run("sh -c " + quote(shell_command), withexitstatus=1)
signal = returncode - 128 # 128+n
print out, signal
```

Or using `pty` stdlib module directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import pty
from select import select
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT

# use pseudo-tty to capture output printed directly to the terminal
master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()
p = Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdin=slave_fd, stdout=slave_fd,
          stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
buf = []
while True:
    if select([master_fd], [], [], 0.04)[0]: # has something to read
        data = os.read(master_fd, 1 << 20)
        if data:
            buf.append(data)
        else: # EOF
            break
    elif p.poll() is not None: # process is done
        assert not select([master_fd], [], [], 0)[0] # nothing to read
        break
os.close(slave_fd)
os.close(master_fd)
print "".join(buf), p.returncode-128
```

Comment: I tried with the shell option, i get the same behaviour:

./dumb2 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
('Exit code was:', -11)
('Output was:', '')
('Errors were:', '')

while outside python I get:

./dumb2 $(perl -e "print Ax50")
DEBUT DU PROGRAMME
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)

Comment: It means that the error message is printed directly to the terminal outside of shell's stdout. You could use pexpect, pty modules to capture such output

Comment: thanks, pexpect seems to be a good alternative, I will try that tomorrow and post the result

Comment: @Tic: I've tested the code on my machine and it works (it captures the message in `err` variable) i.e., you don't need `pexpect` at least on Ubuntu.

Comment: It doesn't work on mine, but pexpect returns the stdout so thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
proc = (subprocess.Popen(called, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE))

print(proc.stdout.read())
print(proc.stderr.read())
```

This should work better.
Personally i'd go with:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

handle = Popen(called, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output = ''
error = ''

while handle.poll() is None:
    output += handle.stdout.readline() + '\n'
    error += handle.stderr.readline() + '\n'

handle.stdout.close()
handle.stderr.close()

print('Exit code was:', handle.poll())
print('Output was:', output)
print('Errors were:', error)
```

And probably use `epoll()` if possible for the `stderr` as it sometimes blocks the call because it's empty which is why i end up doing `stderr=STDOUT` when i'm lazy.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I get the same result, there is no output or error (except '\n')
In the not segfaulting cases, I get something strange, the output is troncatured: only the first line is shown

Comment: @Tic And you're sure that the `called` application isn't segfaulting? This is not reccomended as it can cause your application to hang if to much output, but replace `output += ..` and `error += ...` with `pass` and just let the loop go until the process is finished. After the `while handle.poll()` do a sweep of the output by doing: `output = handle.stdout.read()` and the same for `stderr` as well, see if that catches anything more.. They should perform the same type of operation, but just give it a go and see if it helps.

Comment: Also, do a `python -m trace --trace myscript.py` and see if you get anything useful out of it, it should tell you where your segfault is happening and give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: -1: do not replace `.communicate()` code with `.stdout.read(); .stderr.read()`. `.read()` shouldn't improve anything compared to `.communicate()` but it can deadlock unlike `.communicate()`

Comment: unless you are on Windows; specifying `shell=True` changes the meaning of `called` drastically.

Comment: There could be output buffered even if `handle.poll() is not None`. This is the place where `out += handle.stdout.read(); err += handle.stderr.read()` could be used

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian didn't use shell=True while testing this solution (sorry forgot to mention it, i did it without thinking ^^")
I will edit my system config: it's an archlinux 64 bits

Comment: @Torxed: The segfault is happening in the c program I'm running
in fact called is [./dumb, "A"*50] and dumb has a buffer overflow
I traced it, but didn't found something I could link to the matter :s