# Capturing netcat shell command output in Python

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

I want execute netcat command from my python script, so I use the 'subprocess.Popen', but the problem is that the output of this command is directly printed in may shell console, i want o get him in a variable , so i can do some modification before printing it.

```
res = subprocess.Popen("nc -v 192.168.1.1 25", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
#output = res.communicate()
#output = str(output)
#print output
```

Comment: Have you tried also to redirect `stderr`? It is unlikely that `nc` would print directly to the terminal unless to prompt you for the password

Comment: Here's a [code example that shows how to capture output even if it is redirected to the terminal (outside of stdout/stderr streams)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253472/4279).

Comment: i confirme that, when i use the ls -l in place of nc , it work, so the nc command put the result even if you dont use print command, what could be the solution??

Comment: For something simple like this why not just use a socket directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want make calling shell commands easy to yourself in Python use [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh) library.

In sh this would be:

```
  from sh import nc
  output = nc("-v", "192.168.1.1", "25")  # output is string of the command output
```

As always, [installing Python libraries are recommended to do with virtualenv](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/).

Answer (score 0):

I use this to capture output from a system command, note that it will only get the last line. Modify around lastline as needed to get more:

```
def GetOutput(command):
    lastline = os.popen(command).readlines()
    result = lastline[0].rstrip()
    return result
```