# Python - Using Popen.communicate() does not capture the stdout and stderr of a system call as expected

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a Python script which executes a system call (the call is actually a `java` program).
I am using `Popen.communicate()` to *attempt* to capture the `stdout` and `stderr`. However, it only works for some `Java` applications (of which, ALL the `java` applications I'm calling do display something to the screen when executed directly in the shell).

The code I am using is as follows:

```
    # Perform the java call
    try:

        p = subprocess.Popen(args,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    except OSError as e:
        error_msg = '  Error reading file while executing system command: {0}'.format(e.message)

    except ValueError as e:
        error_msg = '  Error in arugments while executing system command: {0}'.format(e.message)

    else:
        # Display the results in real time
        for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
            sys.stdout.write(line)

        # Grab the stdout and stderr from the process.
        output, err = p.communicate()

    finally:
        # Check to see if an internal error occurred. If not, flip the flag
        if not err and not error_msg:
            java_completed = True
        else:
            java_completed = False
```

In some cases, the line `sys.stdout.write(line)` is never called, and in other's it is.

**Does anyone have any experience with this?**

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that you're reading everything from the process stdout, and then trying to do `communicate` afterwards: you've already read everything from the pipe, so the `output` result from `p.communicate()` will always be empty.

But that doesn't explain why sometimes the `sys.stdout.write` is not being called.

One thing to keep in mind is that there are multiple ways to display things in a console (i.e., in a command window). Printing to the processes stdout stream is only one way, and that's the way that you'll be able to capture with the above code. If I recall from Java days, there is some type of `Console` class that is sometimes used for displaying to the console, this may not use stdout. Also, advanced console display libraries, like `curses` for instance, don't generally write to stdout, they interact with the console object directly. I don't know how, or if, you can capture output from these types of processes, but if it is possible it would probably be very system-specific.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I think the reason I didn't notice that `output` was empty is that I'm really only curious about the `stderr`. But you certainly helped me learn something about how this works. Unfortunately, the question about how to grab output from the `Console` class is still up in the air.

Comment: +1. @Brett: another issue is that you set `stderr=PIPE` but you don't read from it concurrently with `stdout`. It may lead to a deadlock if the program fill the OS pipe buffer corresponding to subprocess' stderr

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Interesting. Any pointers on how I should handle this?

Comment: @Brett: you could try `pexpect`, `pty` modules e.g., [Capture “Segmentation fault” message for a crashed subprocess: no out and err after a call to communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253472/4279) (it fixes the issue if the program writes directly to the terminal).

Comment: @Brett: if you meant how to read both `stdout` and `stderr` concurrently then 1. set `stderr=STDOUT` if it is unacceptable then 2. use threads, or select.select, or fctnl (to make pipes non-blocking), or iocp (on Windows)